# for-each doesn't output values

Tags: scheme

I understand that for-each in scheme doesn't create a new list but in my output, I expected:

```
4
9
16
done.
```

I'm just getting "done".

What's going on here?

```
(define (for-each proc list)
    (cond   ((null? list) "done")
            (else
                (proc (car list))
                (for-each proc (cdr list)))))


(define square (lambda(x)(* x x)))
(square 5)

(for-each square (list 2 3 4))
```

Comment: No languages automatically output the results of their expressions in a for(each) loop. eg. `foreach $i (1..3) { $i + $i }` in perl. Each block evaluate to the double of `$i` but it's neither stored nor printed. I didn't try it in other Algol dialects but I bet you'll find the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the line `(proc (car list))` gets executed for the effect, but its result will be ignored. If you just want to print the results of the square function, try this:

```
(for-each (lambda (x) (display (square x)) (newline)) ; applies function on each element
          '(2 3 4))
=> 4
   9
   16
   done
```

If you want to obtain the results of applying the procedure on each element of the input list, you have to use [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), not [`for-each`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29):

```
(map square '(2 3 4))
=> '(4 9 16)
```

`for-each` iterates over an input list and performs an operation over each element, but only for its *effect* (say, printing each element). It doesn't accumulate the result in an output list, it doesn't even *print* them unless explicitly stated - on the other hand, `map` iterates over an input list, performs an operation over each element and accumulates the result in an output list.

Comment: In for-each, is it possible to display the output for each element?

Comment: @runners3431 Yes it does, but unlike `map`, it doesn't accumulate the result in a list.

Comment: Could i do something like this?   (for-each (display (proc (cdr list))))